# Java - Failed to Merge File from chunked files

Tags: java, spring, io

This question is a sequel question from my previous thread at [Java OutOfMemoryError while merge large file parts from chunked files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34823874/java-outofmemoryerror-while-merge-large-file-parts-from-chunked-files)

I'm successfully implementing the code from the answer and merge large-chunked files into single file without OOME error. **But, the file is always corrupt and different from the original file**.

This is the original code from my previous question,

```
 private void mergeFile(String identifier, int totalFile, String outputFile) throws AppException{
    File[] fileDatas = new File[totalFile];
    byte fileContents[] = null;
    int totalFileSize = 0;
    int filePartUploadSize = 0;
    int tempFileSize = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < totalFile; i++) {
        fileDatas[i] = new File(identifier + "." + (i + 1));
        totalFileSize += fileDatas[i].length();
    }

    try {
        fileContents = new byte[totalFileSize]; // allocating memory to contain all the byte stream for further writing
        InputStream inStream;
        for (int j = 0; j < totalFile; j++) {
            inStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileDatas[j]));
            filePartUploadSize = (int) fileDatas[j].length();
            inStream.read(fileContents, tempFileSize, filePartUploadSize);
            tempFileSize += filePartUploadSize;
            inStream.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new AppException(AppExceptionCode.FILE_NOT_FOUND);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new AppException(AppExceptionCode.ERROR_ON_MERGE_FILE);
    } finally {
        write(fileContents, outputFile);
        for (int l = 0; l < totalFile; l++) {
            fileDatas[l].delete();
        }
    }
}

private  void write(byte[] DataByteArray, String DestinationFileName) throws AppException{
    try {
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(DestinationFileName));
            output.write(DataByteArray);
        } finally {
            output.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new AppException(AppExceptionCode.FILE_NOT_FOUND, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new AppException(AppExceptionCode.ERROR_ON_WRITE_FILE, ex);
    }
}
```

As you can see, from previous question I'm allocating huge amount of array of bytes in order to contain all the files and then write that into single file. Having this technique will give me benefit of the doubt avoid corrupted data while merge the files. But, this will give me OOME (OutOfMemoryError) while merge large file ( > 1 GB).

This is a new merge method using Jim answered

```
private void merge(String identifier, int totalFile, String outputFile) throws AppException{
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>();// put your files here
    for (int i = 0; i < totalFile; i++) {
        files.add(new File(identifier + "." + (i + 1)));
    }

    File output = new File(outputFile);
    BufferedOutputStream boss = null;
    try {
        boss = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output));
        for (File file : files) {
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            try {
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                boolean done = false;
                while (!done) {
                    int data = bis.read();
                    boss.write(data);
                    done = data < 0;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new AppException(AppExceptionCode.FILE_NOT_FOUND, e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    bis.close();//do this in a try catch just in case
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new AppException(AppExceptionCode.ERROR_ON_MERGE_FILE,e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AppException(AppExceptionCode.ERROR_ON_MERGE_FILE,e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            boss.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AppException(AppExceptionCode.ERROR_ON_MERGE_FILE,e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    for (File file : files) {
        file.delete();
    }

}
```

This method can avoid OOME Exception, **but the files is always corrupt...**

Can you show me the fundamental error with this method, or you can provide me a better code...
Many Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be changing the loop like this will solve the problem.

```
        int data = -1;
        while ((data = bis.read()) !=-1) {
            boss.write(data);
        }
```

This way it reduces the chance to write an invalid character into the file.

Comment: Thanks anyway, for anyone having problem while merge thousand even hundred of thousand files... feel free use the code above....